# NotImplementedException for Rest resources in spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, exception

I am developing a Rest Spring boot application and I have my code as:

1. @SpringBootApplication
   public class Initializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   ```
   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(Initializer.class);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Interface which has CRUD methods
3. Many classes which implements the interface
4. Controller classes
5. An exception handler class with `@ControllerAdvice`, a method inside it with `@ExceptionHandler(NotImplementedException.class){ //message }`

I have certain resources with me say `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`.
As of now I have implemented only `a` and `b`, and thus I want to throw a custom  `NotImplementedException` if the client tries to access `c` and `d`.

I want to know where should I throw this exception, do i have to use anything like `ResourceHandlers`, if yes, how to use it and what configurations needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Controller advice class must `extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

2 - Override the original method which handles the exception. In your case:

`public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported (HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request)`

3 - Do what you want to do inside the method you've overriden the handler with.

That's all.